# Canvas wider than containing div (OpenLayers)

Tags: html, openlayers, angular

Map canvas is wider than the containing map div. Causes problems when zoom to extent etc.

Using Angular Material Flex-Layout / OpenLayers 6.

// css

```
.mapContainer {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 16px;
}
 
.map {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
}
```

//HTML

```
<div fxFlex.gt-lg="50" fxFlex.gt-md="50" fxFlex.gt-sm="50" fxFlex.gt-xs="100" fxFlex="100">
    <div class="mapContainer">
        <div id="map" class="map" >
            <div id="tooltip" class="tooltip"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

//Result

Map div width = 793. [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVtcQ.png)

canvas width = 1841. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYiTB.png)

```
<canvas width="1841" height="600" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; transform-origin: left top; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);"></canvas>
```

Edit: The ol.css is imported in the scss (@import '../../../../node_modules/ol/ol.css';).

Comment: It might be because you are not using ol.css (which is also why the control buttons are not displayed correctly)

Answer (score 0):

I use OpenLayers 6 in an Angular 8 app and I added the css link to my HTML page:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@master/en/v6.4.3/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
```

Doing this might help you narrow down the issue to css preprocessor vs something else.  Or just leave it which is what I did (my app is LESS though).